# Block View for specific form

Tags: views

I have two forms on my site. I want to create a Block View for only one of them but as I choose "Webform: Webform form body (Form)" for the Fields in the View, I get both forms showing. I'm trying to only show one of the forms.

I tried adding a css class to a field and then using that as a means of filtering out the fields of just the one form but either I did it wrong or that isn't the way to complete the task.

How can I limit a Block View to show a specific Webform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view, add a filter criteria of 'Content: Nid', then specify the node id of the webform in question. To locate the node id you can edit the webform and look at the url. The url will be /node/xxx/edit where xxx is the nid.

Comment: Wow, thanks. That worked exactly as you suggested.